# Extjs get all store records

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, store

I have one question. Is it possible to get all records which are loaded in a store when the filters are being added to store? For example, if I load into the store 34 records and then apply filters and there is only 15 left, could I get those 34 records without clearing filters?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Edit:** This was originally answered for Ext 4.2, where `snapshot` was public and documented. It is gone nowadays. So here's an update for Ext 5 and 6.

## Ext 5 / 6

One liner:

```
var allRecords = (store.getData().getSource() || store.getData()).getRange();
```

Decomposition:

```
var data = store.getData();
// get unfiltered collection (will be null if the store has never been filtered)
var snapshot = data.getSource();
// pick the one that exists
var unfilteredCollection = snapshot || data;
// get items in an array
var allRecords = unfilteredCollection.getRange();
```

[`Store#getData`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#cfg-data) gives you the store's collection.

[`Collection#getSource`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.util.Collection.html#placeholder-simple-getSource) gives you the store's "source", that is the unfiltered collection -- but only if the collection has already been filtered, otherwise it returns `null`.

In both cases, you'll get a `Ext.util.Collection`. Use [`getRange`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.util.Collection.html#method-getRange) to get an actual array of items.

### Ext 5 `getUnfiltered` method

A `getUnfiltered` method was introduced at some point in Ext 5 (5.0.1 as far as I can tell, but docs for Ext 5 are offline at the moment...). It was not present in the first versions of Ext 5, and it was gone by Ext 6. So, well... Don't use it! Unless you want to tie your code to Ext 5 for no reasons, use the above method.

## Ext 4

*(original answer)*

The whole loaded dataset is stored in the [`snapshot`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-property-snapshot) property of the store.

It is only created when needed though. That means that the property won't be available before some filters have been applied to the store. So to get the information you want in a safe way, use:

```
var allRecords = store.snapshot || store.data;
```

## Ext 4 / 5 / 6

*(and probably future versions)*

You can use [`query`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html#method-query) or [`queryBy`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.data.Store.html?#method-queryBy).

This seems to be the more forward compatible approach since, contrary to the previous methods, this API hasn't changed across versions.

Unfortunately, that will traverse the collection and incurs extra processing cost... Which may or may not be negligible depending of the size of your collection.

```
var allRecords = store
  .queryBy(function() { return true; }) // returns a collection
  .getRange(); // returns array of items
```

Comment: I don't understand why its so hard for Sencha to put a getAllRecords() method on the store. This seems non-intuitive

Comment: Yes... I think that's the kind of issue they're trying to address with the addition of chained stores in Ext 5.

Comment: I would recommend to use `store.query()`, because that is a public and documented API, while snapshot is not.

Comment: @Alexander It was... when it existed. I've updated my answer for newer versions. Thanks for the notification.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps a more forward compatible approach (i.e. ExtJS version >= 5) is the following:

```
var allRecords = store.getData().getSource().getRange();
```

Based on the documentaion, this should work for versions >= 5.0.

Comment: In 6.0.2, I just use:  var recs = store.getRange();

Comment: `store.getRange();` returns only filtered records

Comment: Warning: This only works if the store is currently filtered. Otherwise, it generates a TypeError.

Answer (score 4):

For getting all unfiltered data from a loaded store you can try
var records = store.getUnfiltered();

Note: I am using Ext Js 5.1. Not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: getUnfiltered() is not available in Ext 6.x

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get raw records from http response only - here is my solution:

Add the `getRawRecords` function to `store` class:

```
    Ext.override(Ext.data.Store, {
        getRawRecords: function(){
            return Ext.Array.map(this.getData().getRange(), function(record){
                return record.data;
            });
        }
    });
```

Usage:

```
    var rawData = store.getRawRecords();
```

Answer (score 1):

For my case with ExtJS 4.2.1 (yeah, I know it's old) with a JSON TreeStore, I had to use: `store.proxy.reader.jsonData` since `store.snapshot`, `store.data`, `store.query` or `store.queryBy` did not exist.

Answer (score -1):

In the Latest Extjs 6.2.0 you can use

```
var allRecs = Store.getData().getSource().items
```

Comment: Warning: getSource() returns null if store is filtered. Don't use this.